Optimizing the assignment of variables to DateIntervals for large sets
I have a dataset of 17 time intervals with the form:
dataset1 = {{{1969, 7}, {1970, 2}}, {{1972, 4}, {1973, 4}},...}

The goal is to plot them with "TimelinePlot" and i'm using "Dateinterval" to do so, but it seems that i need to declare each time interval and i'm doing it like this:
event[data_, i_] := DateInterval[data[[i]]]
D1Int1 = event[dataset1, 1]; D1Int2 = event[dataset1, 2]; ...; D1Int17 = event[dataset1, 17];

After that i can plot the time intervals like this:
timeintervals1 = {D1Int1, D1Int2, ..., D1Int17}; Timelineplot[timeintervals1]

However, i need to repeat this process with others datasets and i would like to know if there's an automatic way to declare or assing global variables like "D1Int1" or maybe a way to make only one indexed variable "D1Int(n)" per dataset.
I was trying using "For":
For[i = 0, i <= 17, i++, Print[D1Int[i] = event[dataset1, i]]]

This create the different time intervals of my dataset, but don't assigns any type of variable to them, so the question remains.
Thanks in advance.

You can do the following using Array and FromDigits:
    SetDateInterval[dateIntList_List, identifier_Symbol] := 
    Set @@@ Thread[{Array[identifier[FromDigits[{##}]] &, 
    Length@dateIntList], 
    Array[DateInterval[dateIntList[[FromDigits[{##}]]]] &, 
    Length@dateIntList]}]

    (*Example*)

    SetDateInterval[dataset1, Nio]

